# Ubuntu NFS Client mounts but doesn't see files on Win 2008 Server

Tags: mount, nfs

I have an Ubuntu 17.04 server attempting to connect to a Windows Storage Server 2008 NFS export.  The ubuntu server has full read-write + root access via IP auth on the NFS export.  The Ubuntu server has in the past been able to mount and see the files.  A FreeBSD server running on the same network can mount and see the files.  When the Ubuntu server mounts the export it can see the amount of storage used and available but it cannot see the files.  This issue started roughly 1-2 weeks ago - I don't have an exact date.  I haven't made any changes that would affect this from what I can tell - installed OpenVPN on the server and that is the only change I can recall or see in my notes.

I have tried:

- Unmounting and manually mounting via: mount 192.168.2.11:/media /mnt/nas01/media (Same result)
- altering fstab entry to 192.168.2.11:media /mnt/nas01/media nfs (same result)

**fstab entry:**

> 192.168.2.11:/media /mnt/nas01/media nfs vers=3,auto,nofail,noatime,nolock,intr,tcp,actimeo=1800 0 0

This mount is for a library of media being loaded by Plex Media Server - those options were suggested by members of the PMS community support forum.  It worked with those options since June.

**Relative df output:**

> ```
> Filesystem                  1K-blocks       Used  Available Use% Mounted on
> 192.168.2.11:/media        5797385216 3977598592 1819786624  69% /mnt/nas01/media
> ```

**Relative mount output:**

> 192.168.2.11:/media on /mnt/nas01/media type nfs (rw,relatime,vers=3,rsize=32768,wsize=32768,namlen=255,hard,proto=tcp,timeo=600,retrans=2,sec=sys,mountaddr=192.168.2.11,mountvers=3,mountport=1048,mountproto=udp,local_lock=none,addr=192.168.2.11)

**ls -la output:**

> ls -la /mnt/nas01/media 
>   total 0